# Unexpected Printed Exclamation Mark - cs50 Substitution

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50, c-strings, strlen

Completing cs50's Substitution project. The program is supposed to use a key inputed in the command-line to 'encode' a message (string). My program works fine but for some strange reason it prints an exclamation mark at the end of each cipher. I have no idea why it does this.

So for example, this is what my program prints:

```
$ ./substitution VCHPRZGJNTLSKFBDQWAXEUYMOI
plaintext:  hello, world
ciphertext: jrssb, ybwsp!
```

Instead of the correct

````
$ ./substitution VCHPRZGJNTLSKFBDQWAXEUYMOI
plaintext:  hello, world
ciphertext: jrssb, ybwsp
```
The program: 
```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int key_check(string key);
int char_repeat(string key);
int encryption(string text, string key);

// WHY DOES IT PRINT EXCLAMATION??

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string key = argv[1];
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Ussage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // checking for n of command-line args
    else if (key_check(argv[1]) == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    string text = get_string("plaintext:  ");
    encryption(text, key);
    return 0;

}


int key_check(string key)
{
    // check for valid key
    if (strlen(key) != 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // check for repeated characters in key
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < strlen(key); j++)
            {
                if (toupper(key[i]) == toupper(key[j]))
                {
                    printf("Ussage: ./substitution key\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int encryption(string s, string key)
{
    int position;
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++)
    {
        char c = s[i];
        if (c >= 65 && c <= 95)
        {
            position = c - 65;
            printf("%c", key[position]);
        }
        else if (c >= 97 && c <= 122)
        {
            position = c - 97;
            printf("%c", tolower(key[position]));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", c);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
````

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the index `i` in the range `[0, strlen( key ) )` for the string `s` within the function `encryption` invokes undefined behavior

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++)
{
    char c = s[i];
    //...
```

It seems you mean

```
for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen( s ); i < n; i++ )
```

Or that is better

```
for ( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
```

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like `65` in the program. Instead for example the magic number `65` you could use the integer character constant `'A'` that makes the code more clear and readable.

You have a bug using the magic numbers in this if statement

```
if (c >= 65 && c <= 95)
```

The difference between `95 - 65 + 1` is not equal to `26` that is the length of the string key.

Also the return type `int` of the function

```
int encryption(string text, string key);
```

does not make a sense.

It would be better to declare the function like

```
string encryption(string text, string key);
```

and to return the modified string `text`.

Comment: I have implemented these changes and my code still prints the same message (with the !). Also I don't see how this particular problem is related to an undefined behaviour. (I am new to C, I am asking out of curious ignorance). And why exactly is it an exclamation mark, always?

Comment: @Chris You have also a bug in an if statement. See my updated answer.